# How to move the Green Button to he center with the arrow still next to it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Hi,

So I want to move the button to the center, but still have the arrow and click here next to it. Currently the image (arrow and click here) is pushing it to the center. Can't seem to get it to work without the arrow coming up on the next line. Here is my code (look for GET STARTED NOW [image http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/hand_arrow.png](http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/hand_arrow.png) - any thoughts?

```css
/**
 * Header 17 stylesheet  
 * */
.header-17-startup-antiflicker {
  background:white!important
}
 
.header-17 {
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0
}
 
.header-17 .header-background {
  background:#fff
}
 
.header-17 .navbar {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:0;
  margin:0
}
 
.header-17 .navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
  top:0!important
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .navbar-form {
  padding:30px 0 19px 60px
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .btn {
  padding-left:26px;
  padding-right:26px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:800
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .btn.btn-primary {
  background-color:#16a085
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .btn.btn-primary:hover,.header-17 .navbar .btn.btn-primary:focus {
  background-color:#16a085
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .btn.btn-primary:active,.header-17 .navbar .btn.btn-primary.active {
  background-color:#16a085
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .brand {
  padding-top:33px!important;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-weight:800;
  letter-spacing:0;
  color:#1f2225;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .brand img:first-child {
  float:left;
  margin:0 15px 0 2px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .nav > li {
  margin-left:24px
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .nav > li:first-child {
  margin-left:0
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .nav > li > a {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding:42px 0 24px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#1f2225;
  font-weight:800;
  color:#95a5a6
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .nav > li > a:hover,.header-17 .navbar .nav > li > a:focus,.header-17 .navbar .nav > li > a.active {
  color:#1f2225
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .nav > li.active > a {
  color:#1f2225
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .nav > li.active > a:hover,.header-17 .navbar .nav > li.active > a:focus,.header-17 .navbar .nav > li.active > a.active {
  color:#1f2225
}
 
.header-17 .navbar .navbar-toggle {
  background-image:url(http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/themes/startup/templates/startup-framework/build-wp/common-files/icons/menu-icon-header-17@2x.png);
  -webkit-background-size:17px 12px;
  -moz-background-size:17px 12px;
  -o-background-size:17px 12px;
  background-size:17px 12px;
  margin-top:34px
}
 
.header-17-sub {
  position:relative!important;
  background-color:#1F2225;
  padding-top:105px;
  padding-bottom:105px;
  color:#7f8c8d
}
 
.header-17-sub .dm-carousel {
  height:48px
}
 
.header-17-sub.v-center,.header-17-sub .v-center {
  display:table;
  width:100%
}
 
.header-17-sub.v-center > div,.header-17-sub .v-center > div {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  float:none
}
 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .header-17-sub .v-center.row:before,.header-17-sub .v-center.row:after {
   display:none
 }
 
}
 
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .header-17-sub .v-center {
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   padding-left:5px;
   padding-right:5px
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .v-center.row {
   display:block;
   width:auto
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .v-center.row:before,.header-17-sub .v-center.row:after {
   display:none
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .v-center.row > * {
   display:block;
   vertical-align:baseline
 }
 
}
 
.header-17-sub .row.v-center {
  width:auto
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear {
  font-size:20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:20px 25px 21px;
  background:#16a085;
  border:2px solid #16a085
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear:hover,.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear:focus {
  border-color:#fff;
  background:#16a085
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear:active,.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear.active {
  border-color:#fff;
  background:#16a085;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75)
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear {
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#fff;
  margin:-2px 15px 0 0
}
 
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear {
   font-size:18px;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#fff;
   display:block;
   min-width:260px
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear [class*="fui-"] {
   float:left
 }
 
}
 
.header-17-sub h3 {
  margin:0 0 10px
}
 
.header-17-sub .hero-unit {
  margin:40px 0 60px;
  padding:0;
  background:transparent
}
 
.header-17-sub .hero-unit h1 {
  margin:0;
  font-size:39px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#ffffff;
  line-height:49px;
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:0
}
 
.header-17-sub .hero-unit p {
  padding:20px 0 0;
  font-size:28px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight:300
}
 
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .header-17-sub .hero-unit {
   text-align:left;
   margin:0 0 33px
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .hero-unit h1 {
   margin:0 0 23px;
   font-size:25px;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#ffffff;
   line-height:32px
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .hero-unit p {
   font-size:17px;
   font-weight:normal;
   color:#7f8c8d;
   line-height:23px
 }
 
}
 
.header-17-sub .hero-unit,.header-17-sub big,.header-17-sub h1,.header-17-sub .h1,.header-17-sub h2,.header-17-sub .h2,.header-17-sub h3,.header-17-sub .h3,.header-17-sub h4,.header-17-sub .h4,.header-17-sub h5,.header-17-sub .h5,.header-17-sub h6,.header-17-sub .h6 {
  color:white
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear {
  color:#fff
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear:hover,.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear:focus {
  color:white
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear:active,.header-17-sub .btn.btn-clear.active {
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75)
}
 
.header-17-sub big {
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  line-height:32px
}
 
.header-17-sub h6 {
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-weight:500;
  text-transform:none
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-perspective {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-perspective:1200px;
  -moz-perspective:1200px;
  perspective:1200px
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-page {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform-style:preserve-3d
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-page.pt-page-current {
  position:relative
}
 
.header-17-sub .calculated .pt-page.pt-page-current {
  position:absolute
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-page-current,.header-17-sub .no-js .pt-page {
  visibility:visible;
  z-index:1
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-page-ontop {
  z-index:999
}
 
.header-17-sub .page-transitions {
  margin:85px 0 100px
}
 
.header-17-sub .page-transitions .col-sm-3 {
  text-align:left
}
 
.header-17-sub .img-holder {
  text-align:center
}
 
.header-17-sub .img-wrapper {
  display:inline-block
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-controls {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-100px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-controls .pt-indicators {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-controls .pt-indicators li {
  line-height:18px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:9px;
  height:9px;
  text-indent:-999px;
  background-color:rgba(127,140,141,0.3);
  border-radius:50%;
  cursor:pointer
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-controls .pt-indicators li + li {
  margin-left:10px
}
 
.header-17-sub .pt-controls .pt-indicators li.active {
  background-color:#1abc9c
}
 
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .header-17-sub .page-transitions .col-sm-3 {
   text-align:center
 }
  
 .header-17-sub .page-transitions .col-sm-6 {
   margin:40px 0
 }
 
}
 
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .header-17-sub {
   padding-top:65px;
   padding-bottom:65px
 }
 
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-huge.fui-facebook {
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-huge.fui-facebook:before {
  margin-right:15px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:'Flat-UI-Pro-Icons'
}
 
.header-17-sub .btn.btn-huge.fui-facebook:hover:before {
  color:#fff
}
```

```html
<header class="header-17">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="navbar col-sm-12" role="navigation">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
           </button> <a href="/" class="brand custom-img"><img alt="" src="http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Screen-Shot-2015-03-01-at-1.04.39-PM-e1425234548831.png"> </a>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
           <div class="pull-left">
             <ul class="nav">
               <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
               <li><a href="http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/?p=67">Contracts</a> </li>
               <li><a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
             </ul>
           </div>
           <form class="navbar-form pull-left" action="action">
             <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">GET STARTED </a>
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="header-background">
   </div>
 </header>
 <section class="header-17-sub text-center dm-controlsView-holder" style="background-color: #1f2225">
   <div class="background" style="background-image: url(http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/themes/startup/templates/startup-framework/build-../../../../../../uploads/2015/02/homepage_background-1400x948-53520.jpg); opacity: 0.54">
     &nbsp;
   </div>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
         <div class="hero-unit">
           <h1>Easily create the perfect contract</h1>
           <p>Clever contracts makes it super easy &amp; simple for anyone to create a legally tight contact ready to be signed. We'll guide you through each step.</p>
         </div>
          <a href="/" class="btn btn-huge btn-clear">GET STARTED NOW</a> <img src="http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/hand_arrow.png" alt="image">
         <div id="h-17-pt-1-61" class="page-transitions pt-perspective">
           <div class="pt-page">
             <div class="row v-center">
               <div class="col-sm-3 ani-processed">
                 <big>Protect yourself from lawsuits and a possible court summons.</big>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6 ani-processed">
                 <img width="384" height="191" alt="" src="http://www.clevercontracts.co.za/wp-content/themes/startup/templates/startup-framework/build-wp/common-files/img/header/ticket-clear@2x.png">
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-3 ani-processed">
                 <h6>Live Easy</h6>
                  <span>Creating a contract has never been this easy.Only R89 per contract.</span>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: There's no reason to have something say "Click here" when a button inherently says "click here"...  but I digress.  Try giving your "click here" graphic a negative margin-right the same size as itself.  If it's 150px wide, give it a `margin-right:-150px;` assuming those elements are centered.

Comment: Or make "GET STARTED NOW" as pseudo content, and position it as absolute.

Comment: Make the click here text a background image. If it's 300px, add 300px of padding to both sides of your centered container and put the background image on the right side.

Comment: Hi, I will change the text etc. don't worry one will have click other incentive.

Comment: Hi it worked thanks! Appreciate it really!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the `a` tag and `img` tag with a `div`, center it.. and use positioning on the `img` tag.

```css
section {
  text-align:center;
  background-color:brown;
  }


div.btnwrapper, a.btn
{
  width:10em;
  height:2em;
  display:block;
  overflow:visible;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
  }

div.btnwrapper
{
  position:relative;
  background-color:gray;
  line-height:2em;
}

a.btn {background-color:skyblue;text-decoration:none;}

div.img {
  width:8em;background-color:white;border:0e;display:block;padding:0 1em;
  position:absolute;left:100%;top:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p> This is text </p>
  <div class="btnwrapper">
    <a href="#" class="btn">CLICK ME</a>
    <div class="img">An Image</div>
  </div>
  <p>Other text</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do:

```
.eliminate-offset {
    margin-right: -300px;
}

<img src="..." alt="" class="eliminate-offset" />
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/b6bs2kuh/)**

Off topic: An empty alt attribute is better than "image". Imagine yourself using a screen reader to understand why.